# How can I apply a scaling transformation on widget dynamically by scrolling (Flutter web)?

Tags: flutter, scroll, transformation, scaling

I am creating a web app where the intended functionality is to be able to zoom in and out of the screen (a `Scaffold` Widget ) by scrolling down or up respectively.

I am currently able to achieve that by using this Stateless widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ZoomableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  ZoomableWidget({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      child: child,
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      minScale: 0.5,
      maxScale: 4,
    );
  }
}
```

This widget allows you to zoom in and out of the Child widget by scrolling. My issue is that I want the scaling 'animation' to be in a fixed position (0,0) rather than scaling anywhere on the widget. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is kinda long but it's the only way I could do the same for one of my apps.

**Logic**:
Basically we have to create a function that maps offset of the scrollview to custom scaling values.

**Code**:

This peace of code that maps one range of values to a custom range.

```dart
extension RemapExtension on num {
  num remap(num minExtent, num maxExtent, num minRange, num maxRange) {
    return (this - minExtent) /
            (maxExtent - minExtent) *
            (maxRange - minRange) +
        minRange;
  }
}
```

Now we create a scrollview and add a controller to it to control the scale

```dart
class ScaleOnScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScaleOnScroll({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScaleOnScroll> createState() => _ScaleOnScrollState();
}

class _ScaleOnScrollState extends State<ScaleOnScroll> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  double scale = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // To listen for scroll changes
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        // This will increase the scale when scrolled down between 0.5 and 0.1
        scale = scrollController.offset
            .remap(scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
                scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, 0.5, 1.0)
            .toDouble();

        // This will decrease the scale when scrolled down between 0.5 and 0.1
        //
        // scale = (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent -
        //         scrollController.offset)
        //     .remap(
        //       scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
        //       scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        //       0.5,
        //       1.0,
        //     )
        //     .toDouble();
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SizedBox(
      width: screenSize.width,
      height: screenSize.height,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: 200.milliseconds,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: scale,
              // Replace with widget to scale
              child: Container(
                height: 200.sp,
                width: 200.sp,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: scrollController,
            // To disable debounce effect
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            // Replace with your widget
            child: SizedBox(
              height: screenSize.height,
              width: screenSize.width,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```